# Enemy animation problems godot

Tags: game-physics, godot, gdscript

I have created an enemy for my 2d rpg game in godot but I used AnimationPlayer and don't know how to make my enemy folow me with the right animations

```
onready var sprite = $AnimationPlayer
onready var stats = $Stats
onready var playerDetectionZone = $PlayerDetectionZone


func _physics_process(delta):
    knockback = knockback.move_toward(Vector2.ZERO, FRICTION * delta)
    knockback = move_and_slide(knockback)
    match state:
        IDLE:
            velocity = velocity.move_toward(Vector2.ZERO, FRICTION * delta)
            seek_player()
        WANDER:
            pass
        CHASE:
            var player = playerDetectionZone.player
            if player != null:
                var direction = (player.global_position - global_position).normalized()
                velocity = velocity.move_toward(direction * MAX_SPEED, ACCELERATION * delta)
    
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)

func seek_player():
    if playerDetectionZone.can_see_player():
        state = CHASE


func _on_Hurtbox_area_entered(area):
    stats.health -= area.damage
    knockback = area.knockback_vector * 65


func _on_Stats_no_health():
    queue_free()
    var enemyDeathEffect = EnemyDeathEffect.instance()
    get_parent().add_child(enemyDeathEffect)
    enemyDeathEffect.global_position = global_position
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`AnimationPlayer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animationplayer.html) has a `play` method you can call to tell it to play an animation (you pass the name of the animation as parameter). Usually you would make looping animations and simply call `play` to switch to a different animation when necessary (e.g. when the character changes states).

*I don't see you use the `AnimationPlayer` at all. Plus I don't know which animations do you have, or if you need anything more to make it work for your case. So, I'm limiting myself to the very basic.*